# Multi-Channel EXR Files

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, openexr

I am relatively new to computer vision and image processing. I have a single EXR file with 7 channels: 1-3 give me the RGB values, 4-6 give me the surface normals coded as RGB values and 7th channel contains depth information from the camera of the rendered image. I was wondering if there was any way to view these 7 channels separately. For eg. I would like an image showing only the depth values in grayscale. So far I haven't found a multi-channel EXR file viewer that does this for me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share a link to it? Dropbox, Google Drive, Github...

Comment: Here you go: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NWWEzeiJjx8wdRfsrfpkw37ZvdBnA4sy?usp=sharing

Comment: Those appear to be 4-bands rather than7?

Comment: Could you tell me how did you check for that? I realized it was 4 bands.. once I posted it. Am rendering the 7 band image as I type.